# When I drag an element to another div, the icon is covered by the div, why? JqueryUI

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

The draggable object is li and I am dragging it to the yellow div. The yellow div overlays my dragged object for some reason.

My z-index for the li and ul is higher compared to the yellow and red.

Am I missing something?

[image]

HTML

```
<div id="draggablecontainer">
    <div id="streamWrapper">

    </div>

    <div id="streamers">
        <ul id="streamlist">
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

JQUERYUI

```
 $( "#streamWrapper" ).droppable({
      hoverClass: 'hoverdrop',
      drop: function(event, ui ) {
        var currentID = ui.draggable.attr("id");        
      }
    });
```

CSS

```
#draggablecontainer{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:30px;
background-color: yellow;
z-index:1;
}

#streamWrapper{
position:relative;
padding-top:100px;
height:600px;
font-size:3em;
z-index:2;
background-color: red;

}

.hoverdrop{
position:relative;
background-color: #E0E0E0 ;
z-index:1;
}

#streamPlayer{
position:relative;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
display:block;
z-index:9;

}

#streamers{
position:relative;
height:600px;
border-top:2px solid #D0D0D0  ;
overflow: auto;
z-index: 10;
}

#streamlist{
height:500px;
width:900px;
position:relative;
list-style:none;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding-top:50px;
margin-top:0px;
z-index:10;
background-color: blue;
}

#streamlist li{
position: relative;
z-index:4;
padding-left:80px;
list-style:none;
height:60px;
width:150px;
float:left;
margin-right:20px;
margin-bottom:10px;
color:black;
background-color: #D0D0D0 ;
border:1px solid #C0C0C0 ;
display:block;
moz-box-shadow:    1px 1px 1px 1px #787878 ;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #787878 ;
box-shadow:         1px 1px 1px 1px #787878 ;
z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: We need to see the html and css

Answer (score 0):

Please see this http://jsfiddle.net/bsWCA/ . I just created empty li since there was no li 's in your code. If i removed all the z-index i was able to get it work correctly. If you could post your code in js fiddle except for the video , it might be easy. Try removing z-index since as far as i know z-index might be the reason for the issue.

```
//html
<div id="draggablecontainer">
    <div id="streamWrapper">

    </div>

    <div id="streamers">
        <ul id="streamlist">
            <li> Hello </li>
            <li> Hello </li>
            <li> Hello </li>
            <li> Hello </li>
            <li> Hello </li>


        </ul>
    </div>

</div>


//js
$( "#streamWrapper" ).droppable({
      hoverClass: 'hoverdrop',
     accept:"#streamlist li",
      drop: function(event, ui ) {
        var currentID = ui.draggable.attr("id");        
      }
    });

$("#streamlist li").draggable({
scroll:"true",
scrollSensitivity:100,
revert:false,
helper:"clone",
appendTo:"body"
}); 

//css
#draggablecontainer{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:30px;
background-color: yellow;

}

#streamWrapper{
position:relative;
padding-top:100px;
height:600px;
font-size:3em;

background-color: red;

}

.hoverdrop{
position:relative;
background-color: #E0E0E0 ;

}

#streamPlayer{
position:relative;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
display:block;


}

#streamers{
position:relative;
height:600px;
border-top:2px solid #D0D0D0  ;


}

#streamlist{
height:500px;
width:900px;
position:relative;
list-style:none;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding-top:50px;
margin-top:0px;

background-color: blue;
}

#streamlist li{
position: relative;

padding-left:80px;
list-style:none;
height:60px;
width:150px;
float:left;
margin-right:20px;
margin-bottom:10px;
color:black;
background-color: #D0D0D0 ;
border:1px solid #C0C0C0 ;
display:block;
moz-box-shadow:    1px 1px 1px 1px #787878 ;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #787878 ;
box-shadow:         1px 1px 1px 1px #787878 ;
z-index:10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. the ul was inside a div #streamlist which caused it only to be draggable within that div. I just removed that div completely.